# Why javascript IF/ELSE doesn't work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and I want to make username validation on registration form. I don't know what's wrong on my code but I think I have a problem with "IF ELSE" statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#usernameErrorMsg").hide();
  var usernameLength = $("#username").length;
  $("#username").focusout(function() {
    checkUser();
  });
  function checkUser() {
    if (usernameLength < 5 || usernameLength > 20) {
      $("#usernameErrorMsg").show();
    } else {
      $("#usernameErrorMsg").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

I expected that when I input more than 5 char until 20 char, the usernameErrorMsg will disappear. The actual result, no matter how many characters that I have input, the error message keeps coming up.

Answer (score 3):

`usernameLength` is being computed only once, before `checkUser()` ever runs. You should re-calculate its value inside the callback each time; otherwise, changes to that value will not be visible inside the callback.

Furthermore, if you want to check the length of the test in the input, you need to check `$("#username").val().length`, not `$("#username").length`:

```
function checkUser(){
  var usernameLength = $("#username").val().length;
  if (usernameLength < 5 || usernameLength > 20){
    $("#usernameErrorMsg").show();
  } else {
    $("#usernameErrorMsg").hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd just use `const` here instead of `var` - this value probably will never be changed

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut I've not tested the code myself; the question lacks an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to compare against.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#username").length` is not the length of the characters in the field. It's the amount of elements in the JQuery wrapped set returned from your query. Since only one element will have an `id` of `username`, the length is always `1` and your `if` condition will always be `true`.

What you'll have to do is get the length of the ***value*** in the field:

`$("#username").val().length`

You'll also want to move the line that gets the value into the `focusout` event handler so that you are always working with the most current data.

Lastly, it doesn't make much sense to have a function do nothing but call another function, so you can combine the `checkUser` function with the event callback and simplify the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#usernameErrorMsg").hide();  
 
  var username = $("#username");        // Find the element just once
  
  $("#username").focusout(function() {
    // Each time the user leaves the field, get the current
    // amount of characters in the input field
    var usernameLength = username.val().length;
  
    // See the difference between the length of the JQuery query and 
    // the length of the value of the first element in the results?
    console.log(username.length, usernameLength);
    
    if (usernameLength < 5 || usernameLength > 20) {
      $("#usernameErrorMsg").show();
    } else {
      $("#usernameErrorMsg").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: <input id="username">
<span id="usernameErrorMsg">ERROR</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `length` of `input` everytime the function checks it.

Currently you calculate the `length` only once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#usernameErrorMsg").hide();

  $("#username").focusout(function(){
    checkUser();
  });

  function checkUser(){
   //calculate the length everytime in the function
    var usernameLength = $("#username").val().length;

    if(usernameLength < 5 || usernameLength > 20){
      $("#usernameErrorMsg").show();
    }
    else{
      $("#usernameErrorMsg").hide();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#usernameErrorMsg").hide();

  $("#username").focusout(function(){
    checkUser();
  });

  function checkUser(){
    usernameLength = $("#username").length;
    if(usernameLength < 5 || usernameLength > 20){
      $("#usernameErrorMsg").show();
    }
    else{
      $("#usernameErrorMsg").hide();
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding an explanation of why it works, and addressing the problem that $("#username").length does not actually return the length of the user name.